# autocomplete ajax and php not working for more than one input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

html:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<label for="InputBox1"><b>~</b><font color="red">*</font>: &nbsp;</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<div id="1"></div>
<p id="InputBox1Error"></p>
<input id="input" name="InputBox1" style="width: 250px;" onblur="InputBox1()">
<div id="suggest"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

javascript (inline):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#input").keyup(function(){
$("#suggest").html("");
var input = $("#input").val();
input = $.trim(input);
if(input){
$.ajax({
url: "ajax.php",
data: "input="+input,
success: function(msg){
$("#suggest").html(msg);
}
});
}
});
});
</script>
```

javascript source file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#input").keyup(function(){
$("#suggest").html("");
var input = $("#input").val();
input=$.trim(input);
if(input){
$.ajax({
type:'POST', 
url: "PathToPHPfile",
data:"input="+input,
success: function(msg){
$("#suggest").html(msg);
$("#suggest ul li").mouseover(function(){
$("#suggest ul li").removeClass("hover");
$(this).addClass("hover");
})
$("#suggest ul li").click(function(){
var value=$(this).html();
$("#input").val(value);
$("#suggest ul").remove();
if(input.value != ''){
document.getElementById("input").style.backgroundColor = "#BFFFBF";
}
});
}
});
}
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#suggest").autocomplete({ // myevent_name is the id of the textbox on which we are applying auto complete process
                        source:'<?php echo get_bloginfo("template_url");?>/PHPfile',
                        minLength:1
                    });
                });
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$dbh=mysql_connect ("~", "~", "~") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db ("~") or ("Database not found");

$input = $_REQUEST['input'];

$input = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($input));

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ~ WHERE ~ LIKE '%".$input."%'";

    $data = mysql_query($sql);

    $arrcnt = -1;

    $dataArray = array();

    while ($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) 
        {
            foreach($temp as $key=>$val) {
                $temp[$key] = stripslashes($val);
                $arrcnt++;
        }
        $dataArray[$arrcnt] = $temp;
    }

    $list = "<ul class='unorganised' style='width:100;height:auto;'>";

    foreach($dataArray as $val) {
        $list .= "<li class='list'>".$val['~']."</li>";
    }

    $list .= "</ul>";

    echo $list;









?>
```

My main question: this works for one input box (id="input").  I'm trying to apply this to 10 input boxes on the same HTML page, so that each input box has autocomplete functionality from same table in mysql database.  Autocomplete functionality doesn't perform for input box (id="input2") and so on (I changed variable names to other input box ids).  In other words, how to apply this logic to multiple input boxes on same HTML page?  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your jQuery is targetting only the one box by it's id:

```
<div id="suggest"></div>
```

Instead consider:

```
<div> 
    <input id="input" name="InputBox1" style="width: 250px;" onblur="InputBox1()">
    <div class="suggest"></div>
</div>
```

then: (your inline javascript)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input").keyup(function(){
            var suggestionBox = $(this).next('.suggest');
            suggestionBox.html("");
            var inputValue = $.trim($(this).val());
            if(input){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    data: "input="+inputValue,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        suggestionBox.html(msg);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: the issue is that the first input box is correctly displaying the autocomplete functionality in the "suggest" div, however the second isn't ...

Comment: If you copied it exactly, did you at least give a new id to the second input box?

Comment: not working ... nothing is appearing in suggestion box ... is it something in my external .js file or my .php file?

Comment: try not running the external .js file for now

Comment: one suggest div works when the id of that div is called "suggest" ... otherwise, not ... when both (two input boxes) have same div id of "suggest", still only first one works ...

Comment: don't use `id="suggest"` use `class="suggest"` see my example above.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yj29cmf0/1/

in this case, since jsFiddle can't access the remote url the error function is the one setting the `div.suggest` but otherwise it works

Comment: exact code not working ... nothing in suggestion class / div

Comment: you have a url i can visit?

Comment: "<input id="input" name="~" style="width: 250px;" onblur="~">
<div id="suggest"></div>" works ...

Comment: "<input id="input" name="~" style="width: 250px;" onblur="~"> <div class="suggest"></div>" doesn't work with code I have...

Comment: Are you using my code for javascript because the fiddle works. The only way that your `<div id="suggest">` would get hit at all is if you changed my `var suggestionBox = $(this).next('.suggest');` into `var suggestionBox = $(this).next(#suggest');`

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my answer, you have to change your inline JS to my JS as well and lose the similar portions n your external JS

Comment: What do I fill in the "url: ~" field?